# slicing data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, cross-validation

This is likely a really simple question, but it's one I've been confused about and stuck on for a while, so I'm hoping I might get some help.

I'm using cross validation to test my data set, but I'm finding that indexing the pandas df is not working as I'm expecting. Specifically, when I print out x_test, I find that there are no data points for x_test. In fact, there are indexes but no columns.

```
k = 10
N = len(df)
n = N/k + 1
for i in range(k):
    print i*n, i*n+n
    x_train = df.iloc[i*n: i*n+n]
    y_train = df.iloc[i*n: i*n+n]
    x_test = df.iloc[0:i*n, i*n+n:-1]
    print x_test
```

Typical output:

```
0 751
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
751 1502
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, ...]
```

I'm trying to work out how to get the data to show up. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [sklearn.cross_validation.KFold](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.KFold.html#sklearn.cross_validation.KFold)? There is a clear example on this site...

---

**UPDATE:**

At all subsets you have to specify columns as well: at `x_train` and `x_test` you have to exclude target column, at `y_train` only the target column have to be present. See [slicing and indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) for more details.

```
target = 'target' # name of target column
list_features = df.columns.tolist() # use all columns at model training
list_features.remove(target) # excluding "target" column
k = 10
N = len(df)
n = int(N/k) + 1 # 'int()' is necessary at Python 3
for i in range(k):
    print i*n, i*n+n
    x_train = df.loc[i*n: i*n+n-1, list_features] # '.loc[]' is inclusive, that's why "-1" is present
    y_train = df.loc[i*n: i*n+n-1, target] # specify columns after ","
    x_test = df.loc[~df.index.isin(range(int(i*n), int(i*n+n))), list_features]
    print x_test
```

Comment: I'd rather build my own, that way I can see how it's implemented